# Visual studio feature - commenting code Ctrl K - Ctrl C

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I commented on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100420/hidden-features-of-visual-studio-2005-2008/129876#129876) some time ago regarding how visual studio comments out code with `//` or `/* */`. I was thinking to revise the answer (to include my findings) but I had to test it first, which kind of confused me.

My finding is that depending on what you comment when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> you will get either `//` or `/* */`.

### First example:

```
<start selection here>    code();
                          someCall();
                          thirdCall();<end selection here>
```

this will produce the following:

```
//code();
//someCall();
//thirdCall();
```

### Second example:

```
    <start selection here>code();
                          someCall();
                          thirdCall();<end selection here>
```

this will produce the following:

```
/*code();
someCall();
thirdCall();*/
```

### Third example

```
    <start selection here>code();
                          //someCall();
                          thirdCall();<end selection here>
```

this will produce the following:

```
//code();
////someCall();
//thirdCall();
```

Note that example 2 and 3 is the exact same selection, but the comment makes Visual Studio interpret it differently.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach one would expect is to use // for any selection that is made up entirely of *complete* lines, and /*...*/ for anything that starts/ends mid-way along a line.

...which is what it seems to actually do.

Comment: What do you mean by complete lines?

Comment: If you put the cursor at the left edge (on column 0) and then press shift+down, you will select a complete line. That is, all the text from column 0 to the end of the line, plus the newline at the end.

Comment: exactly, that is [1]. But when selecting from column 4 (where the text starts) you get /* */. I hope my edit made it clearer.. I also found out that it has something to do with comments..?

Comment: It seems this is a C++ specific behaviour. I can understand it using // instead of /* */ if the lines to comment include a multiline comment (because they cannot be nested). I presume that if you include a // comment it is taken as a "hint" that you simply prefer // comments to /* ones?