# Why Does VS 2010 'Comment' Keyboard Shortcut Change in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

For me, Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> keyboard shortcut is used to comment-out the selected lines. When editing C++, this sometimes uses block comments (`/* */`) and sometimes uses line comments (`//`). Why does it change? How does it decide which to use when?

Comment: +1: I haven't used VS for years but I remember the behaviour you describe. Good question. I could never work out the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple other discussions on the topic:

[Visual studio feature - commenting code Ctrl K - Ctrl C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891344/visual-studio-feature-commenting-code-ctrl-k-ctrl-c)

[visual studio C++ toggle comment ? comment while not whole line is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350744/visual-studio-c-toggle-comment-comment-while-not-whole-line-is-selected)

Based on my own tinkerings, and what was said in those articles...

It's based on the start/end of the selection. It seems to use double slashes `//` whenever you start your selection at the beginning of the line AND end it at the end of a line.

It will use `/*  */` notation whenever the selection occurs midway through lines.

IE:

If I have the code

```csh
int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

and highlight only `int main`, it will convert it to `/*int main*/`.

If I highlight the entire code section, starting after the indent tab, it will convert it to

```csh
/*int main () {
    return 0;
}*/
```

But if I highlight the section starting before the indent tab, it converts it to

```csh
//int main () {
//    return 0;
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary of links under Zhais' answer. Because following links is hard!

- Selecting entire lines (including leading whitespace) will use `//`
- Selecting at least one partial line

  - If a `//` comment is included, will use `//`
  - Otherwise, will use `/* */`