# Keyboard shortcuts for Visual Studio C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium and mostly use it for C#, but recently I've been starting to dust off my C++.

I'm used to the C# 2005 keyboard shortcuts, and that's how I had Visual Studio installed, but whenever I'm editing a C++ file, it reverts to a different keyboard shortcut scheme (where format is Ctrl+K,Ctrl+F).

Is there a way I can configure Visual Studio to use the C# 2005 shortcuts when I'm editing C++ files?

EDIT: Apparently C++ and C# are using the same shortcuts, but this shortcut schema doesn't support "Format Document" for C++.  What I was actually seeing in C++ files was "Format Selection".  All in all, my question was a little premature.

Comment: Actually, the formatting text shortcut seems to be the only one.  The other shortcuts I thought were different turned out to be features Visual C++ does not have, like Rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find help [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2010/07/25/vs-2010-keyboard-shortcuts-for-c-vb-c-f-now-available-in-letter-8-5x11in-and-a4-210-215-297mm-print-ready-sizes.aspx) and [also a MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx). Also see this [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708571/why-does-vs-2010-comment-keyboard-shortcut-change-in-c)

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: While this doesn't exactly answer my original question, that question turned out to be more a matter of general confusion, and one of the provided links did help clarify some of the confusing symptoms I was seeing, so I'll mark this as the answer.