# How to show all implement instance of an interface method?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my project, there are tons of interface classes used. I have difficulties in reading to understand the code since browsing the definition of the codes (by selecting the method name and pressing F12 or right click + go to Definition) just lead me to the interface.

Is there a way (built-in or addon) in Visual Studio 2010 to list out all of the instance of a method of an interface?

Hope to hear from you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a while, I found that just with VS 2010, I can archive this all alone: Use "Call Hierarchy"!

1. Place your cursor on any member of the interface class
2. Right click and choose "View Call Hierarchy"
3. Open the "Implements..." node in the "Call Hierarchy" pane.

That's it. Enjoy ^_^!

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this and is an excellent addition to VS.net for many other reasons that you'll discover...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it costs quite high for me (USD200 for personal used)...