# What are some useful shortcut keys in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Similar Post:**
>   [Hidden Features of Visual Studio (2005-2008)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100420/hidden-features-of-visual-studio-2005-2008)

What are some shortcut keys you know of that make programming faster, easier, or all around more enjoyable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Of course there is Intelli-Sense, it opens automatically or when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Select the variable / class / function or whatever it shows you and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert it.
2. Code snippets, also provided by the Intelli-Sense list insert code so you do not need to type everything again. Etc. type "prop" and double hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to format your total file so it looks cleaner.
4. `#region / #endregion` to group your code and allow you to hide the whole region

Answer (score 7):

One of my favorite items is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to add an imports/using statement to the top of the code file.

Comment: Shift + Alt + F10 is the same...

Comment: I didn't know that was another way of doing it.  Nice!

Comment: +1 I have by far found this to be one of the most useful, hidden gems in the VS IDE.

Answer (score 3):

I like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, which formats the code in a file.

And although it's not a Visual Studio feature, I highly recommend [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Answer (score 2):

Couple of my favorites:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> -- moves you between open code pages
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> -- allows you to do a search across the entire solution (as sometimes find all references does not work when your solutions get huge)
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd> -- allows you to remove an entire line from your code without highlighting it.

Comment: SHIFT + DELETE is cut not delete entire line (just thought I clear that)