# Visual Studio 2008 Tweaks

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tweak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden Features of Visual Studio (2005-2008)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100420/hidden-features-of-visual-studio-2005-2008)

Please share tweaks, tips and tricks that you know for Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for getting the paste history.