# How can I make Visual Studio wrap lines at 80 characters?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to make Visual Studio word-wrap at 80 characters?  I'm using VS2008.

[This post is loosely related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/vertical-line-after-a-certain-amount-characters-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Is this a personal thing, or do you have an instructor for a class that requires it? I would find line wrapping at all rather... restrictive to my coding style, as I like to use long descriptive names for things. ^_^

Comment: I'm with Nicholas Flynt - restricting code to 80 characters per line is typical for uni assignments, but is in my opinion rather unproductive in The Real World[TM].

Comment: Maybe 80 is too restrictive... but I prefer a relatively narrow setting because it lets me see the whole statement at once, without auto-hiding the toolbox and other auxiliary windows.

Comment: Restrict column width has many advantages. Read this: http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000545.html

See this: http://vulcan.eager.googlepages.com/whereis.png

Comment: I always allow word wrap for everything except Python, where it's confusing - precisely because I like to use long, descriptive names and want to see everything on the line, not just the first bit

Comment: @thepeer In my opinion, if your names are long enough to force word-wrapping, they are probably too long to be easily readable, which actually makes your code *harder* to understand. (Though my experience is based on trying to read lots of code with long "descriptive" names bordering on the pathological--some method names were 80+ characters on their own.)

Comment: @KyleStrand I'm with you.  I find code a lot more understandable if I can view it on one screen.  When I posted this 8 years ago, I was a little more dogmatic about wanting my 80 characters (because if its good enough for a console, its good enough for studio!).  Now, I'm happy if i can just see everything at a reasonable font size.

Comment: I got here looking for a way to *hard* wrap a block comment. (I agree with others that auto-wrapping code is not likely to be that useful, though some amount of discipline in limiting line length in comments and code can help when diffing during code reviews, etc.) Not finding what I was looking for, I did find this rewrap tool: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap Haven't tried it, but it looks like it would do the job.

Comment: .editorconfig files have a setting for this, but VS does not support it. You can upvote the request to add that support here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-max-line-length-in-editorconfig-for-visual/567214

Comment: See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> All Languages >> General >> Select Word Wrap.

I dont know if you can select a specific number of columns?

Comment: VS 2013: no option for the number of columns; However the wrap is adjusted if you change the size of the VS window.

Comment: I do not think this is the wanted behavior, at least not what I want. Is there a way to set the width of a line ?

Answer (score 132):

Unless someone can recommend a free tool to do this, you can achieve this with [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/):

ReSharper >> Options... >> Languages/C# >> Line Breaks and Wrapping

- Check "Wrap long lines"
- Set "Right Margin (columns)" to the required value (default is 120)

Comment: In R# 8.x it's under
RESHARPER >> Options >> Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Line Breaks and Wrapping

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 (with ReSharper 2020.1) the path is now Extensions >> ReSharper >> Options >> Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Line Breaks and Wrapping

Answer (score 37):

I don't think you can make VS wrap at 80 columns (I'd find that terribly annoying) but you can insert a visual guideline at 80 columns so you know when is a good time to insert a newline.

[Details on inserting a guideline at 80 characters for 3 different versions of visual studio](http://dream-runner.blogspot.com/2007/06/visual-studio-tips-80-character.html).

Comment: Alternative link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 26):

You can also use

`Ctrl+E, Ctrl+W`

keyboard shortcut to toggle wrap lines on and off.

Comment: Thanks, does it stay enabled for all files forever, or just the session?

Comment: thanks for this shortcut...I misstype this a lot and always have to google where to disable it. gonna put this on a post-it not for sure

Answer (score 9):

To do this with [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) (another non-free tool):

VAssistX >> Visual Assist X Options >> Advanced >> Display

- Check "Display indicator after column" and set the number field to 80.

Comment: Now under VAssistX >> Visual AssistX Options >> Display

Answer (score 5):

Adds vertical column guides to the Visual Studio text editor. This version is for Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015.

See [the plugin.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da227a0b-0e31-4a11-8f6b-3a149cf2e459/view/Reviews)

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this question when was actually searching for an answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio) (how to add a visual line/guideline at char limit). So I would like to leave a ref to it here for anyone like myself.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is simply that you want to know when you pass 80 characters for a single line, which is a common coding guideline limit, you can use a different approach: [Editor Guidelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.EditorGuidelines). This will add vertical column guides behind your code.

Answer (score 1):

VS only supports [Word Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236529/3850405). At least up until latest 17.7.4 version available today.
There is a [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-max_line_length-in-editorconfig/567214?q=max_line_length)  to support `max_line_length` for `editorconfig` but it probably wont be implemented anytime soon. The issue has been there since 2019.

On another note I think you should read Linus Torvalds note from Linux Kernel Mailing List on 80 characters per row limit [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/5/29/1038). Good points about why excessive line breaks can be bad.

Comment: Thanks!  I gave up on the 80 character limit a long time ago, but I appreciate your response.  The note from Linus is of course well-reasoned and acerbic, as all of his writing is.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315531/193017) in order to switch the mode conveniently.

Citation:

> I use this feature often enough that I add a custom button to the command bar.
>
> Click on the Add or Remove -> Customize
>
> Click on the Commands tab
>
> Select Edit|Advanced from the list
>
> Find Toggle Word Wrap and drag it onto your bar

Answer (score 0):

You can enable word wrap and set zoom of code for 207% and that will show wrap every line of code that is over 80 characters in length.

Comment: This seams to work only on a specific resolution screem

Answer (score 0):

I have created a .NET analyzer to get warnings (code LK0080) on your warnings list whenever you cross the 80 chars limit.
It is NuGet package: LeetKean.Analyzers.LineLength