# How can I toggle word wrap in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, word-wrap

Does Visual Studio .NET have a way to toggle word-wrap on and off?

I am used to this feature in Eclipse which allows you to right click and toggle word wrap on and off so that when you have long lines that extend out to the right, you don't have to move the bottom scroll bar right and left to read your code/html:
http://web.archive.org/web/20131027224437/http://ahtik.com:80/blog/2006/06/18/first-alpha-of-eclipse-word-wrap-released/

Comment: Compared to other editors such as Notepad++, Sublime Text and Visual Studio Code, word wrap in Visual Studio has several known issues. If you use it, please vote for the feature request [Fix known issues with word wrap](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/891314/fix-known-issues-in-word-wrap-1.html).

Comment: @ColonelPanic That link goes to an issue marked as a duplicate that cannot be voted on. This issue can be voted on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351760/fix-known-issues-in-word-wrap.html

Answer (score 748, accepted):

Following *[Manage word wrap in the editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-manage-word-wrap-in-the-editor)*:

**When viewing a document**: Edit / Advanced / Word Wrap (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)

**General settings**: Tools / Options / Text Editor / All Languages / Word wrap

Or search for 'word wrap' in the Quick Launch box.

---

[Known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-manage-word-wrap-in-the-editor?view=vs-2017#known-issues):

> If you're familiar with word wrap in Notepad++, Sublime Text, or Visual Studio Code, be aware of the following issues where Visual Studio behaves differently to other editors:
>
> 1. Triple click doesn't select whole line
> 2. Pressing End key twice does not move cursor to end of line

If you'd like these bugs fixed, **please vote for the feature request** [*Fix known issues with word wrap*](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351760/fix-known-issues-in-word-wrap.html).

Comment: When I press the 'end' key, the cursor moves to the end of the displayed line not the actual line - _really_ annoying. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I had to check the "Show all settings" at the bottom to get All Languages to show up in the options.

Comment: Very annoying as I constantly use CTRL + E, F to reformat code with R# and CTRL + E, W is just way too close.

Comment: I have no Edit->Advanced... is Visual Studio Community hobbled in this way?

Comment: Oddly, my settings under 'options' as you described were checked for this, but it wasn't wrapping. I unchecked the box and rechecked it, then after exiting the window my code wrapped (in VS Professional 2017).

Comment: Cool. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 29):

I use this feature often enough that I add a custom button to the command bar.

1. Click on the **Add or Remove Buttons** -> **Customize**
2. Click on the **Commands** tab
3. Click **Add Command...**
4. Select **Edit** (or Edit|Advanced for newer VS versions) from the list
5. Find **Toggle Word Wrap** and drag it onto your bar

Comment: Couldn't find the bloody thing! Great solution.

Comment: its REALLY hard to find and there is no search.

Answer (score 15):

As of Visual Studio 2013, the word wrap feature is finally usable—it respects indentation. There's still a couple of issues (line highlighting, selection), but it's worth using. Here's how

[image]

Comment: interesting. I wonder if there's a way to *not* respect indentation if I don't want it

Comment: I disagree that it's usable as even now in 2022 it still doesn't even support configuring which column it wraps at.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2005 Pro:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Or menu *Edit* → *Advanced* → *Word Wrap*.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2008, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the output window.
2. Look for the little icon on the very right-hand side of the toolbar that starts with the text "Show output from:" in it.  It looks like a small window with a carriage return icon.  When you hover over it  Visual Studio should display "Toggle Word Wrap" near your mouse pointer.
3. Click that icon.

You now have learned something that was so painfully obvious I feel embarrassed for not knowing this long ago and thus have chosen to pay my dues and share my answer with others so they don't suffer the same agony I have.

Seriously, this is really useful for those with small screens.  I have a small Lilliput USB monitor that is good for small tool windows, Skype IM, etc.  It works great for putting the output window on, except that it sucks having to always sideways scroll.  After just putting up with sideways scroll for months I finally decided to see if I could make it word wrap.  The answer was so easy but the amount of time/effort it saves is tremendous.

Answer (score 5):

[keyboard shortcuts in visual studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

(alt + z) => toggle word wrap

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I can't find the settings described above in my version 2019

Comment: @MagicLAMP, In your current version of visual studia code check for keyboard shortcuts reference

Comment: To be clear, the link in this answer is for Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2008 it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Use menu *Edit* → *Advanced* → *Word Wrap* in Visual Studio 2003.

Answer (score 3):

For `Visual Studio 2017` do the following:

**Tools > Options > All Languages**, then check or uncheck the checkbox based on your preference. As you can see in below image :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In latest version.

1.click the left bottom of the icon [setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm3Aq.png)

2.select setting [setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dlKC.png)

3.select "text editor"> "word wrap" on [word wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II6RV.png)

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code === Version: 1.52.1

1. Open VS Code **settings**
2. From the settings find the settings.json file and open it
3. add this code - **"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"**

If you already added **"editor.accessibilitySupport"** with the value **"on"** before then simply turn it to **"off"**. This is the code worked for me when I faced the same problem while working with one of my JS Project.