# javascript display single line visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded a js file.

When I open it in Visual Studio 2010, it displayed the file as a single line.
How to format it?

Comment: Is it minified/crunched?  Most production Javascript code is run through a process that removes all whitespace.

Comment: Do you also need to enable [word wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/315511/759019)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use this** :

[Beautify, unpack or deobfuscate JavaScript and HTML, make JSON/JSONP readable, etc.](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: `+1`, this is a cool tool (just ran it on my production YUI crunched JavaScript, and works well)

Comment: press Beautify JavaScript or HTML button or Ctrl+Enter