# Show codes in next line instead of horizontal scroll in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

in Visual Studio 2012 i didn't have horizontal scroll in my editor, if my code goes long it continue in next line, i want to know how to do like this in Visual Studio 2013?
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I toggle word wrap in Visual Studio.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315485/how-can-i-toggle-word-wrap-in-visual-studio-net)

Comment: i searched but i didn't find solution sorry for duplicated question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try going to Options --> TextEditor --> All Languages and make sure that Word Wrap is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

The default key binding to toggle word-wrap in Visual Studio is Ctrl-e+Ctrl-w.