# Horizontal scroll behavior

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

I've been enjoying my Visual Studio Code switch over from Dreamweaver so far, but I just can't get used to the horizontal scroll behavior. The current behavior is that when I try to scroll to the side, it moves the cursor rather than the scroll bar. It scrolls so fast and wraps to the next line, that I find it a bit obnoxious to view code off to the side. This is such a completely foreign and new concept to me, that I just can't get use to it. I would much rather just stick with the arrow keys for this behavior.

The only setting I could find is the scroll sensitivity, but that just isn't cutting it for me. Is there some key binding or setting, that I can use to have normal horizontal scrolling behavior?

Additionally; Are there more settings not listed in the defaults and if so, where or how can I find more?

Comment: Hm, I wonder if this is an issue with the scrolling itself, are you using a thumb like on a Thinkpad or an external mouse or touchpad?

Comment: I am using an 'ELAN Pointing Device' touchpad mouse, on Windows 10 Home. The drivers used are for Windows 8.1, but they seem to be working properly.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with VSCode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1200

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504708/show-codes-in-next-line-instead-of-horizontal-scroll-in-visual-studio

Answer (score -2):

### TRY WORD/LINE WRAP

---

Unless there's a specific reason why you want to constantly scroll right/left in your code use line wrapping.

#### Edit your settings.json via (File->Preferences->User Settings) and add config settings for wrapping.  Choose 0 for wrappingColumn and select your indentation preference.

`
    //---EDITOR CONFIG---

```
// Controls after how many characters the editor will wrap to the next line. Setting this to 0 turns on viewport width wrapping
"editor.wrappingColumn": 0,

// Controls the indentation of wrapped lines. Can be one of 'none', 'same' or 'indent'.
"editor.wrappingIndent": "indent",
```

`