# How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using code files, you typically don't need longer lines to wrap around. However, with `.md` files this is in fact rather useful. However, **I can't seem to find the option to enable word wrap** so longer lines will be wrapped.

To reproduce, open Visual Studio Code resized to a small-enough window, and enter the following text in a new document:

```
This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum.
A linebreak before this.
```

The effect is this:

[image: Example of missing word wrap]

I'm trying to get the horizontal scrollbar to stay away, having line 1 wrap around at the right side of the window.

I've done a few things to answer my own question:

- [Search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvscode%5D+word+wrap): zero results at the time of writing this;
- Meticulously going through the menu of Visual Studio Code: didn't find it;
- Using the Command Palette with "wrap": gives no matching commands.

Perhaps it's not possible, and I'd need to file a feature request? Or am I missing something?

Note that I'd like to be able to turn it on and off quickly. For one, @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned in comments this solution to change wrapping behavior in the settings, but I'm looking for a quick command or menu option to do this (much like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 2 have).

Comment: I think this was just added in VS Code 0.3. Check the [list of new features](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates) for wrapping control

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622631/how-to-wrap-text-comments-in-visual-studio-code) from another StackExchange site shows that you can simply add `"editor.wrappingColumn": 0` in your user settings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the suggestion. That would be somewhat of a workaround, because word wrap is typically something I want to switch on/off quickly. I've updated my question accordingly. It may still be useful to turn your comment into an answer though, for others that land here who may be fine with that workaround.

Comment: Its now "editor.wordWrap": true

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[How can I toggle word wrap in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315485)*

Comment: For those using Eclipse Theia or gitpod.io: Go to File -> Settings -> Open Preferences -> editor -> `wordWrap` -> set it to `true`.

Comment: There are a lot of solutions, if they don't work, then restart your virtual studio code IDE, then it may work.

Answer (score 1363, accepted):

Since v1.0 you can toggle word wrap:

- with the new command *editor.action.toggleWordWrap*, or
- from the *View* menu (*View** → *Toggle Word Wrap*), or
- using the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keyboard shortcut (for Mac: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).

It can also be controlled with the following settings:

- *editor.wordWrap*
- *editor.wordWrapColumn*
- *editor.wrappingIndent*

---

Known issues:

1. [renderLineHighlight should highlight the entire logical line](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36839)

If you'd like these bugs fixed, please vote for them.

Comment: Completely agree that this should be a thing we can manually enable/disable on a per-window basis. Right now I'm going though a .txt file with a bunch of log entries, and having word-wrap enabled makes it challenging to read. Usually I don't mind it, but in this instance would like it disabled.

Comment: Just implement it as it is currently in Sublime. That's perfect!

Comment: @Benjamin, what about 'wrap to window'?  That's something I personally use a lot in certain code files (like MarkDown as he said).

Personally, I'd love to see three options accessed quickly: Off (No wrapping), Window (wraps to viewable extents) and Specified Column (which would pick up the value in the preferences.)  Then be able to assign keyboard shortcuts to flip between those three.

Comment: This is no acceptable solution if you need to set `"editor.wrappingColumn": -1` by default. Use case is: I work a lot with code files. Only in some case (*.md files) I must toggle word wrap but cannot!

Comment: For that you can leverage our language specific settings introduced in 1.9 (see http://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_settings)

Comment: Wicked ALT+Z or pressing View > Toggle Word Wrap doesn't do absolutely anything.

Comment: Please report issues like that to our repository (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/)

Comment: however it's not working for me with big files. only work with very small files.

Comment: editor.wordWrap is a better option to add word wrap for all files.

Comment: ALT+Z fires the nVidia GeForce Experience overlay for video capture etc. Only way is via the menu which is acceptable.

Comment: Alt-Z works on a Lenovo T420 Thinkpad running Ubuntu 18.

Comment: NB you can do this on a per file or file type basis by adding `"[markdown]": {"editor.wordWrap": "on"}` this creates a file type override for the setting

Comment: somehow, you can hit alt+z by accident doing some other formatting stuff and the word wrap settings does absolutely nothing with it, you have to find this answer and hit alt+z again, this time on purpose

Comment: If you want that word wrap on every session, please change `editor.wordWrap` in `settings` menu.

Answer (score 78):

**`wrappingColumn` has been deprecated in favour of `wordWrap`.**

Add this line to settings.json to set wordWrap on by default:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on"
```

or open user settings:

Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Then search for "wordWrap" or scroll through the 'Commonly Used' settings to find it and select 'on'

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but don't [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028495/419956) and [this other earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397785/419956) also mention exactly that already?

Comment: They don't mention that wrappingColumn has been deprecated

Answer (score 76):

Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *User Settings*.

It will open up Default Settings and `settings.json` automatically. Just add the following in the `settings.json` file and save it. This will overwrite the default settings.

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{ "editor.wrappingColumn": 0 }
```

[image: Screenshot of settings being edited.]

Comment: with latest version its, "editor.wordWrap": "on" is setting above one wont work.

Comment: Yes, this setting was changed in VSCode 1.10. Here's the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_word-wrap-settings-redesign

Comment: Open settings.json for me is easiest F1 > backspace key > enter settings.json > find the one in .config

Answer (score 39):

Since [version 0.3.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_3_0), wrapping has been put in the command palette. You can activate it with *Toggle Word Wrap* or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to get remembered and has to be applied again every time.

Answer (score 35):

Check out this screenshot (*Toogle Word Wrap*):

[image]

Answer (score 27):

[Since 1.9](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_language-specific-settings), it's possible to select a specific language for word wrap settings (or any settings). You can find this in the command palette under:

**Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings...**

Which will take you to your "settings.json" for a selected language where you might include:

```
"[markdown]": {
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
  "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn"
},
```

Comment: How do you get to *"Configure Language Specific Settings"*?

Comment: One route is from the menu `View => Command Palette...` You can then type "Configure Language Specific Settings..."  (or just "Lang set"). The Command Palette is a really good way of finding anything in vscode, it's worth learning the shortcut.

Answer (score 27):

Go to the *Preferences* tab (menu *File* → *Settings*), and then search as “word wrap”. The following animated image is helpful too.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

If you want to use text word wrap in your Visual Studio Code editor, you have to press button <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> for text word wrap. Its word wrap is toggled between text wrap or unwrap.

Comment: This is covered by the highest voting, accepted answer.

Comment: On mac, use `option` + `Z`

Answer (score 26):

Here you go with *word-wrap* on **Visual Studio Code**.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Using the Command Palette works for this question, but also for many similar other questions:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (macOS <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)
2. The keyboard shortcut opens the "**Command Palette**"
3. Search for "toggle wrap" or just "wrap"
4. Set your preferences for "Toggle Word Wrap"

Notes:

- Works for version 1.55.2 and up
- Default shortcut is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>
- The "Command Palette" will show you the keyboard shortcut for your option too

Screenshot:

[image: top of the VSCode editor with the command palette open and ">toggle wrap" typed, showing the answer with its keyboard shortcut]

Comment: for the latest version

Comment: You can edit your answer if you wished to add "for the latest version" :)

Comment: that default note `alt + z` was really helpful!

Comment: I'm the original poster of the question, and for what it's worth this would now be my preferred answer. The reason: the CTRL+SHIFT+P combination opens the 'Command Palette' and _not only_ fixes my original problem, but _also_ nearly all similar features _and_ anno 2023 will teach you the keyboard shortcut for your intended purposes inside the resulting options in the palette!

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable word wrapping in .md documents by default? I have to use ALT + Z to disable it.. This isn't the case with other file types such as .json?

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure when it was added, but I'm using v0.10.8 and
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for turning word wrap on and off. This satisfies the requirement of "*able to turn it on and off quickly*".

The setting does not persist after closing Visual Studio Code. To persist, you need to set it through Radha's answer of using the `settings.json` file...

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{ "editor.wrappingColumn": 0 }
```

Comment: I had to use { "editor.wrappingColumn": -1 } to make it the default.

Comment: `editor.wrappingColumn` has been deprecated, use `editor.wordWrap` instead.

Answer (score 9):

[Word wrap settings redesign](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_word-wrap-settings-redesign)

Here are the new word wrap options:

```
editor.wordWrap: "off" - Lines will never wrap.
editor.wordWrap: "on" - Lines will wrap at viewport width.
editor.wordWrap: "wordWrapColumn" - Lines will wrap at the value of editor.wordWrapColumn.
editor.wordWrap: "bounded"
```

Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport width and the value of `editor.wordWrapColumn`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But this info was also already in the top-voted answer. I suggest adding the short bits of explanation for the new options to that answer as an edit.

Comment: Was looking some clarity regarding the meaning of the different options. I played with the values and it was basically between `boundend` and `on`, in the end I decided to go with `on` as if you have more space in your window it will not wrap, while `bounded` wraps to `editor.wordWrapColumn` (default is `80`) even if there is more space in the window so for me personally `on` the most sensible but it's personal of course. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 9):

Explained here [Language-specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings) but specifically:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P and type "Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings"
2. Select the language or add section in the file (start typing "[" to see list of suggestions) or edit section as you like if already there.
3. If set it to `bounded` you might need to adjust the `editor.wordWrapColumn` value to wrap depending on the screen size. With `bounded` *Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport and editor.wordWrapColumn*

Example:

```
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 200,
    "[markdown]": {
        "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    },
    "[plaintext]": {
        "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    },
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer for users who want to permanently turn it off. Turning it off in preferences has no effect if it is set to `on` in the language preference.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried solutions from about 5 other pages before I found this and it finally kicked in. I saw the `"[markdown]": {"editor.wordWrap": "on"},` syntax elsewhere, but couldn't make that work in my settings.json file; it's invalid json. The `Ctrl`+`Shift` + `P` route worked.

Answer (score 6):

This is from the VS Code docs as of May 2020:

> Here are the new word wrap options:
>
> ```
> editor.wordWrap: "off" - Lines will never wrap.
> editor.wordWrap: "on" - Lines will wrap at viewport width.
> editor.wordWrap: "wordWrapColumn" - Lines will wrap at the value of editor.wordWrapColumn.
> editor.wordWrap: "bounded" - Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport width and the value of editor.wordWrapColumn.
> ```

So for example, if you want to have the lines wrapped at the boundary of the window, you should:

1. Open `settings.json` (Hit CTRL+SHIFT+P and type "settings.json")
2. Put `"editor.wordWrap": "bounded"` in the json file, like this:

   ```
   {
     ... ,
     "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
     ... ,
   }
   ```

and then it should work.

Answer (score 5):

If it's not working in mac,
**make sure to tell VScode that you are not using a screen reader**.

I had word wrap on and restarted VScode, and it gave me a notification window saying that if I'm in a screenreader, yes or no, and to **note that word-wrap does not work in screen readers**.

Comment: This is what work for me

Comment: In my case it was due to grammarly app

Answer (score 4):

- **Windows:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + press the key "P". Now on the command line, type *Toggle Word Wrap* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- **Mac:** <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + press the key "P". Now in the command line, type *Toggle Word Wrap* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

For Dart check "Line length" property in Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Accessibility support is on by default and it will override your selected wrapper behavior.
So disable Accessibility Support first.

Then choose "on" for the Word Wrap option.
You don't need to go into `settings.json` to enable word wrap.

[Picture of the accessibility support option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBsOt.png)

Comment: That should change with VSCode 1.73, Oct. 2022: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95428

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Access to Dart extension settings

[image]

Step 2: Find Dart: Line Length, set it to 132 and then save settings
[image]

Step 3: Press Alt + Shit + F and you will see the lines are wrapping as configured.
[image]

Comment: Isn't that _formatting_ instead of _wrapping_ though?

Comment: Formatting (ALT+ SHIFT + F) uses the wrapping configurations.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I was thrown off because my original question (and most answers) was about "_Soft Wrapping_" to prevent scrolling, not so much _hard wrapping_ (in your screenshot there's still a horizontal scroll bar, I was trying to prevent exactly that when writing the question back then).

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on Settings in VS Code editor
2. Search for wordwrap
3. Select "on" for the Editor Word Wrap as shown in screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Mac: **Code** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** -> Type *wordwrap* in *Search settings* -> Change *Editor: Word Wrap* from **off** to **on**.
- Windows: **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** -> Type *wordwrap* in *Search settings* -> Change *Editor: Word Wrap* from **off** to **on**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a permanent solution for wordwrapping lines, go to menu *File* → *Preference* → *Settings* and change `editor.wordWrap: "on"`. This will apply always.

However, we usually keep changing our preference to check code. So, I use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> key to wrap written code of a file or you can go to menu *View* → *Toggle Word Wrap*. This applies whenever you want not always. And again <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo wordwrap (will show the full line in one line).

Comment: Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.52 and above go to **File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Diff Editor** and change **Word Wrap** parameter as you wish

Answer (score 1):

The language-specific example by @Riga is great. For a general setting, I would recommend the following:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 90,
"editor.wrappingIndent": "same",
```

This wraps text if your viewport is smaller than the column limit (90 here) and uses the same indent when wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

When opening a huge file showing a notification. The notification guides towards disabling the huge file optimizations (i.e., it instructs how to configure `"editor.largeFileOptimizations": false`). Once that is done, word wrapping works even for huge files.

Answer (score 0):

I am here to for the users who want to disable wrapping but could not succeed.

if disabling doesn't work after you changing the settings around VS code, i.e., the "wrap words" option in control pallete (ctrl+shif+P), or pressing alt+Z, then it is time to look at the extention you have installed.

In my case, i was working with Dart and installed Dart extension. This is what I did.
open the extension:
[image]
click the gear icon, choose "extention settings", type "wrap", you will see
[image]

change it, done!

Answer (score 0):

Since VSCode 1.86 (Jan. 2024), you can disable wrapping for specific languages. Even SCM input (like Git commit message).

See [issue 200884](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200884) for illustration:

> Using the latest [VSCode Insiders release](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), you can use language specific editor configuration to disable word wrap:
>
> ```json
> "[scminput]": {
>   "editor.wordWrap": "off"
> }
> ```