# Visual Studio Code Word Wrap

Tags: word-wrap, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable Word Wrap in Visual Studio Code Version 0.10.6?  I have tried to find the option in settings but have had no success.

Comment: Any chance this is helpful? https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/9739698-word-wrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How to switch word wrap on and off in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-to-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-vscode)*.

Answer (score 6):

`editor.wrappingColumn` is deprecated now, instead of adding that setting use this:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on"
```

Answer (score 2):

The option is   "editor.wrappingColumn", and you need to set it to 0 for wrapping.

So, go to File / Preferences / User settings and edit the settings.json file, adding the following line:
        "editor.wrappingColumn": 0,