# Code line wrapping in a long javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have following object that does not fit into my coding screen:

```
{"hide(), show(), toggle(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), fadeTo(), fadeToggle(), slideDown(), slideUp(), slideToggle(), animate(). Something different for text(), html(), and val() , attr() and load() ": "after each functions callback function can be executed?"},
```

Breaking it after the comma does not work. Neither `\n` is helping here.

How can I break the code so it would be easier to maintain it?

Comment: what IDE/Editor are you using? VSCode has a setting for this

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Also consider using prettier (https://github.com/prettier/prettier) for your codebase. You can try it online: https://prettier.io/playground/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use word wrapping/line wrapping features of your IDE.

In Visual Studio Code:

> Since v1.0 you can toggle word wrap:
>
> - with the new command editor.action.toggleWordWrap,
> - from the View
> - menu (View > Toggle Word Wrap), or using the ALT+Z keyboard shortcut
>     (for Mac: ⌥+Z).

Source [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-to-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-vscode)

Or you can use javascript string concatenation with `+` sign like this to build the key string and use it in your object:

```
var key = "hide(), show(), toggle(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), fadeTo(), "+
          "fadeToggle(), slideDown(), slideUp(), slideToggle(), "+
          "animate(). Something different for text(), html(), "+
          "and val() , attr() and load() "
var obj = { [key] : "after each functions callback function can be executed?"}
```

or if you prefer in one statement:

```
var obj = { ["hide(), show(), toggle(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), fadeTo(), "+
          "fadeToggle(), slideDown(), slideUp(), slideToggle(), "+
          "animate(). Something different for text(), html(), "+
          "and val() , attr() and load() "] : 
          "after each functions callback function can be executed?"}
```

Comment: that will console.log // { key: "whatever" }

Answer (score 2):

In ES6 you can use bracket notation to define an object key name like this:

```
const fooObj = {
  [fooName]: 'some nifty message'
}
```

Where `fooName` can be a variable holding a valid string. Mixing this with template literal strings you could do something like this:

```
const fooName = `
fee(),
fi(),
fo(),
fum(),
Homie I am not playing with you
`;
const fooObj = {
  [fooName]: 'some nifty message'
}
```

And that should work