# how to disable word-wrap in VS Code for a specific file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using windows and VS Code, I have few files that I do not need to wrap them wherever I press Alt+Shift+F, is there a way to disable auto format wrapping for specific files?

Comment: I found this other post that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-to-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-vscode

Comment: yes, I have seen these before, they are for the whole app, I need to apply it to specific file.

Comment: I doubt you can turn off word wrapping for specific files - you can for all files of a language but you probably don't want that.  You could turn off formatting of `specific` files by altering the keybinding for formatting but that requires you to set a regex that would match the files you want excluded.  Let me know if you want to see that method.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. Want ONLY txt files to be warp and not a long line. If you a solution for this, it would be helpful to share it.

Answer (score 21):

Explained here [Language-specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings) but specifically:

1. CTRL+SHIFT+P and type "Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings"
2. Select the language or add section in the file (start typing **[** to see list of suggestions) or edit if already there.
3. If wrapping, depending on columns available in your editor you might want to update `editor.wordWrapColumn`. *Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport and `editor.wordWrapColumn`*

Example:

```
   ...
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 200,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    },
    "[plaintext]": {
        "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
    },
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't toggle it off, for some reason, even though I was changing the global setting. I didn't realize there were language-specific wrap settings. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like VSCode [allows for this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings). You can tweak it as you prefer for each file type.

However note that there have [been reports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25357) of it not working for markdown files.
I guess it is something still being tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this person made an extension that might be useful for you.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.setting-toggle

Looks like you can setup a few quick easy setting toggles. would at least make it quicker as you're bouncing from file to file.

Comment: This extension toggles the setting for the whole app, I need to disable word wrapping for specific files.