# How do I reduce the width of my editor file in vscode so that I don't have to scroll to the right to reach the end of a paragraph

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, code-editor

It seems my lorem ipsum paragraphs in vscode end up as one long line causing me to have to scroll to the right rather than a paragraph of text appearing.

[image]

How do I reduce the width of the editor box so I don't have to scroll to the right when putting large amounts of text?

Comment: have a look at this [turn on word wrapping in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap text by pressing **option + z** shortcut on mac or **alt + z** shortcut on windows

If you'd rather reduce the font text you can use **command + minus sign** shortcut on mac and **ctrl + minus sign**  shortcut on windows

Comment: Thank you very much!