# How can I increase line limit?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to increase the line size. in half of the screen the typing line is going to the next line. how can I increase this limit?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028495/4901118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either disable word wrap, or adjust the wrapping width (number of columns) to your liking in the settings.

[image: Word Wrap settings: VSCode]

Correspodning `settings.json` entries

`"editor.wordWrapColumn": 120,` and `"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",`

Comment: Thanks really appreciate.. this is working now Thank you very much