# Disable auto line breaking in Java Formatter - VSCODE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, formatter, google-java-format

I need to disable this auto line break my code in Java VS CODE Formatter

It's wrong

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I was annoyed that the Java Language extension for vscode was breaking up commented code, so I increased the default column line length from 80 to 200 in java-formatter.xml `<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.line_length" value="200"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you open the wordWrap, but your current code length exceeds the max-length which has been set by default.

There're two solutions to your question, writing it in Settings.json:

1.Turn off the wordWrap:

```
    "editor.wordWrap":"off",
```

2.Still keep wordWrap on but changing the code's max-length:

```
   "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
   "editor.wordWrapColumn":200,
```

Comment: It doesn't for for Java. But just for others type of documents.