# VS Code set right margin to text

Tags: visual-studio-code

Good Morning. I have followed several posts on the net, but I can not solve. I would like to put a right margin on the text in the editor. I have set the variable editor.rulers, as described below. I get the 80 character marker, but the text goes over it. How can I do this? Thank you.

```
// Columns at which to show vertical rulers
"editor.rulers": [80],
```

Comment: Loot at the `word wrap` settings.  Rulers are just indicators, they won't actually wrap your text at their locations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. I think it's an unsupported option.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code