# Visual studio code : remove word wrap line on editor

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Please help I need to remove the below line when editing .dart files on visual studio code.

[Visual studio code editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYPfh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Hi, thank you for assisting, I managed to find a way to fix it. i edited settings.json under
"[dart]": {
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ]
    },

I removed that setting and everything was fine.

Comment: who has added this `dart` specific setting, 80 chars was for VGA screens, we now have 4K monitors

Comment: We have found 125 is a good number to avoid wrapping and scrolling on laptop screens while not making monitors look like it's scaled to print on a toilet roll

Comment: @rioV8 Exactly! It's extremely annoying to have that line

Comment: You could also need to set "editor.formatOnSave": false in the [dart] section of the settings. That works for me in addition of removing editor.rules

Answer (score 4):

1. Shift + CMD + P.
2. Type "settings"
3. Click on "preferences: open settings(JSON)"

That will **open settings.json** file, **then remove the "editor.rulers" and save it.**
The vertical line will be gone.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It's a read-only json

Comment: after those steps I think you should reload your vscode it worked