# How to remove the printer limit line in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521959/visual-studio-code-remove-word-wrap-line-on-editor), but the solution didn't work since the settings file was read-only.
I'm referring to this annoying line that shows up in the IDE:
[image]

I've had a look at the IDE settings, but there's no way to get rid of the line. At least in Netbeans there was an option. While it's just unbelievable that someone thought it was necessary to add that line there in a modern IDE, for now could anyone share a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Is that line at 80 columns?  It looks like it is the right edge of the editor, not a column marker.

Comment: It's a the 81st column. This is for a new Flutter project I created. Mark, I know when a line is not the right edge of the editor :-)

Comment: You didn't open the correct file: `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` is the correct file - you opened `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`.