# VS Code line break or wrap

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, line

When I write code in Visual Studio Code, and the line gets long, It doesn't break. It goes past the edge of the screen and that is rather annoying. What I want is for the line to break and then go on below, I believe this is called wrap or breaking I'm not sure. I use a split screen on my computer so only one half is my code editor and the other half is my project so I can see as I update it. Any help?

Comment: Try toggling word wrap with the shortcut of "Alt + Z". This would wrap a line if it goes off the screen

Comment: bellow is same answer
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 6):

### Command

`Ctrl+Shift+P` to open command palette and type `wrap` there.

### Windows

`Alt+Z`

### Mac

`⌥+Z`

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting for that called `editor.wordWrap`.

You can search the settings for "wrap" and set some additional customization to how you want VSCode to behave when wrapping text.