# How to enable word wrap for just one file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I have a JavaScript file that has very long one-line comments, I want to set `"editor.wordWrap": "on"` for this file only and keep other js files unwrapped.

I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but it doesn't persist on VSCode reload. Are there any better ways?

Comment: You _can_ enable per language, like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678794/6530134, so just for your javascript files.  Closer, but not for a *single* file

Comment: @TimothyG. The feature request for specific files is tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112280).