# Visual Studio Code line wrap

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been having a problem with Visual Studio Code for a long time. When I write code and save it, the line automatically wraps itself, which over time has caused the code to become more difficult to read.

I'm sick of it and would like to know if there is any way to disable it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

From settings you can choose whether to enable or disable word wrap.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code) a similar question.

1. Go to `File > Preferences > Setting (Windows)` or `Code > Preferences > Settings (macOS)`
2. Type `word wrap` into the search field and you will see the search results immediately. Head to the Editor: Word Wrap section
3. Select `on` from the drop-down

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).