# How to collapse/fold a link in Visual Studio Code Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

It is hard to read a markdown document in Visual Code if it contains links with long URLs. Is there a way to collapse/fold link addresses?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from looking through the markdown settings (you can try it yourself by triggering autocomplete/suggestions after typing `markdownlink` in a settings.json file), there is no setting that enables the behaviour you are looking for.

One possible workaround would be to just read the markdown preview (instead of the source markup). You can do this with the buttons at the top right, or with these commands and keyboard shortcuts:

- `Markdown: Open Preview` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)
- `Markdown: Open Preview to the Side` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd>)
- `Markdown: Open Locked Preview to the Side`

If you want the feature you are asking for, you can create a feature request on [their GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other options that make the long URL situation a bit more bearable:

1. Disable word wrap (*View* menu or press *ALT-Z*).
2. Use Reference Links

Example:

```markdown
    This is a [reference link][myexample]

    [myexample]: https://the-url
```

See also [How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code#31028495)