# How can I wrap a long line to fit on the screen in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Long text content in vs code]

How to break my content text so that it could be visible in together?

Comment: Toggle Word Wrap: `Alt + Z`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025502/how-can-i-switch-word-wrap-on-and-off-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Start dealing with vs code shortcuts.
Try the shortcut `alt + Z`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31025502/11107541. see also the guidance in [answer] on answering duplicates.