# How to stop VSCode from breaking regular text in <p> tags?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to stop VS Code from breaking up regular text in my `<p>` tags into separate lines?

I do have prettier installed but i'm not sure if that's what's doing it:

[image: lorem ipsum text breaking example]

Comment: disable all extension and see if that fixes the problem, I don't have that problem and I don't have prettier

Comment: is this soft wrap or hard wrap? for soft wrap, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31025502/11107541