# Automatically break lines in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vim, there's an option `set textwidth=100` which breaks a line at the length 100. Together with autocmd and other plugins, I can make more complicated rule on how to break line. I mainly use vscode to edit latex files, and I want the following feature: If it's in math mode, then don't break long lines, and if it isn't in math mode, break a line at the length 100. In vscode, how to achieve this?  I think it is hard since I have to determine it's in math mode. In vim, this can be done with tree-sitter or vimtex. In vscode, is there any way to achieve this?

I tried with the vscode-neovim plugin. However, it seems that insert mode of nvim doesn't take effect, and editing actions are mainly done in the vscode, not in the backend nvim.

Comment: you want soft wrap or hard wrap? see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31025502/11107541

Comment: Does a Latex extension work for you? Some extensions (like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathematic.vscode-latex) use latexindent.pl which seems to have a line break option.

Comment: @starball I want hard wrap. I know this thread, but it's not exactly what I want.  I want to break a line only when it's not in math mode. In vim, I can do this with the help of vimtex.

Comment: @andber1  latexindent.pl does't work. I used it several times and it only works well for simple latex source file.