# How to auto split and wrap long strings with Resharper reformat code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

```
var record = new Record("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec posuere lacus at eros rhoncus, nec tempor nunc pulvinar. Aliquam ut placerat nisl, a dignissim leo. Integer condimentum nibh et leo dapibus dictum. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisi a velit lacinia, sit amet euismod ipsum egestas. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus eu nunc porta, sagittis eros sed, semper dolor. Integer mollis nulla id quam dapibus vehicula. Vestibulum quam justo, interdum in metus sit amet, ultrices lobortis nulla. Proin id erat vehicula, interdum nisl sit amet, malesuada tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum sed volutpat eros. Curabitur a neque tempus, dictum turpis eget, facilisis eros. Suspendisse eget neque eleifend, volutpat diam at, sollicitudin mi. Vestibulum luctus sed sapien vel elementum. Nam gravida risus sed dui pharetra euismod.");
```

I want to see it like this:

```
var record = new Record("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " + "Donec posuere lacus at eros rhoncus, nec tempor nunc pulvinar. " +
    "Aliquam ut placerat nisl, a dignissim leo. " + "Integer condimentum nibh et leo dapibus dictum. " +
    "Vestibulum ullamcorper nisi a velit lacinia, sit amet euismod ipsum egestas. " +
    "Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. " +
    "Phasellus eu nunc porta, sagittis eros sed, semper dolor. " + "Integer mollis nulla id quam dapibus vehicula. " +
    "Vestibulum quam justo, interdum in metus sit amet, ultrices lobortis nulla. " +
    "Proin id erat vehicula, interdum nisl sit amet, malesuada tortor. " + "Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum sed volutpat eros. " +
    "Curabitur a neque tempus, dictum turpis eget, facilisis eros. " +
    "Suspendisse eget neque eleifend, volutpat diam at, sollicitudin mi. " +
    "Vestibulum luctus sed sapien vel elementum. Nam gravida risus sed dui pharetra euismod.");
```

Comment: If you just want to visually wrap the lines, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236517/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-wrap-lines-at-80-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to put the carret wher you want to split and hit enter. It'll do it for you

Comment: I always have to do it this way. May be I should make an extension for R#.