# Visual Studio equivalent to Rewrap to limit comments and text to 80 characters?

Tags: visual-studio, comments, word-wrap

Is there a Visual Studio equivalent to Rewrap (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap)? This looks like exactly what I want to limit comments and other text to 80 characters, but it is for VS Code. Is there something like this for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236517/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-wrap-lines-at-80-characters

Comment: Yes, I wanted something more robust than a guideline. Ideally, I would be able to highlight an area of text and hit a keyboard shortcut and it would auto-format it.

Comment: [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net) can reformat comments to a specified width. This question will probably be closed as off-topic at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrap is available for both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio.

The Visual Studio one is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.Rewrap-18980