# Visual Studio voice commands

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, voice, code-by-voice

you know how Iron Man was using voice commands for his IDE in the movie? Are there any Visual Studio plugins that can do that kind of thing? If not, how do you go about making them yourself?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Along that vein, I would like it to recognize "fix bug"

Comment: +1 for making me aware of the existence of the "code-by-voice" tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Visual Studio Voice Commands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ce35c120-405a-435b-af2a-52ff24eb2c30)

Soon to be called Bob I think!!

Answer (score 2):

There's a plug in I use at home that works well but is slightly finicky. It doesn't do the actual programming, but more of an aid to eliminate the shortcuts. Essentially, any function that you can run using shortcut commands you can run using this plug in. To get a list of the available functions go to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247076.aspx).

It's [ThirdHand at codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/thirdhand) and as far as I can tell it only works on VS 2008 since it uses .Net 3.5. Make sure to read my post on in the discussion board on how to reset it if there are any problems.

It's been awhile since I've seen in the movie, so I hope this is similar to what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

With [Vocola](http://vocola.net) it's pretty easy to create voice commands for Visual Studio or any other application. Here's an example which connects a spoken phrase to a keystroke sequence:

```
Save File = {Ctrl+s};
```

When you say "Save File" it sends the keystroke "Control-s", and your file is saved.

A few useful commands for Visual Studio (note "#" is the comment character):

```
Find in Files = {Ctrl+F};
Switch Tab = {Ctrl+Tab}{Enter};
Close Solution = {Alt+f}t;
Touch Go = {LeftButton}{F12};                    # "Go To Definition", e.g. of method name mouse is pointing to
Touch References = {RightButton}a;               # "Find All References", e.g. of method name mouse is pointing to
Rename All = {Alt+Shift+F10} Wait(100) {Enter};  # Renames all references, e.g. to a method you just renamed
```

With a little thought about what commands you need and a little practice using them, programming gets a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Microsoft Speech SDK, as well as Visual Studio Integration. There are a BUNCH of tutorials (just google) on both, and in VS2008 there's even templated Integration projects out of the box...

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The answer is somewhat unspecific, but so is the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Sempu VS extension. It also allows you to set your own commands.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2964c90-68e2-4ddd-861a-bd66e5cd4434

Not yet compatible with VS 2013 (preview) as of this date, accepted answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I code by voice in Visual Studio and [SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350348/can-i-write-sql-using-speech-recognition) using Dragon NaturallySpeaking Professional. I've been doing this for years, and played around with creating my own add-ins for Visual Studio. They harvest my class and variable names and help me build my custom programming vocabularies. Unfortunately, saying "fix bug" would simply dictate that text, but I can write code and control the IDE pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Dragon NaturallySpeaking Professional Version you could probably make use of some of the following scripts which I have created using Visual Basic Advanced Scripting for Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

https://github.com/Mark-Phillipson/DragonScripts/wiki/Visual-Studio-Commands

Comment: The link has been changed to a live one

Comment: I have refreshed the link to github