# SQL Server for the visually impaired

Tags: sql-server, accessibility

Is there a tool for the visually impaired to write and run queries against SQL Server databases? How is the best way to accomplish this? `sqlcmd` is a bit messy for this purpose.

Comment: visually impaired is rather vague.. you could use SQL Server management studio and have a rather large font size or set the default text editor color combination of your choice if color blindness is the problem,

Comment: Well, English is not my first language, so I am afraid to write some politically incorrect terms. I was referring to blind people. :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350348/can-i-write-sql-using-speech-recognition

Answer (score 0):

This Stackoverflow thread discusses some good options:

[Can I write SQL using speech recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350348/can-i-write-sql-using-speech-recognition)

I think there are many speech-to-text tools you can use, but the assumption would be that you would be within SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), in a Query Window connected to your database, and that you understand SQL pretty well. For example, Intellisense would not prove to be helpful. Returned results displayed in the grid or as text could be audibly read back to you using your computer speaker with text to speech technologies.

Significantly, however, I think there will still be challenges, but where there is a will there is a way!

Comment: Thank you, @DanielG. The goal here is to aid a new programmer who is blind. So I think a friendly text-to-speech IDE would be the best. He has said that he have already worked fine with mysql command line tool, that's why I mentioned `sqlcmd`.