# Column guides in editor for SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is there a way to get column guides (e.g. a vertical line at column 80) in SSMS 2012? I see ways to do this [in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84209/667632) and [previous versions of SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332577/667632), but I don't see anything for SSMS 2012.

I tried a new string called `Guides` with the value `RGB(128,0,0) 80` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Text Editor`, but after restarting SSMS 2012 there was no guide line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSMS 2012 has updated editor control, that does not support "simple" way to display guidelines, as it was in 2008 (using registry settings).

I develop SSMSBoost add-in (www.ssmsboost.com) and in last release (v.2.12) we have added Guidelines functionality for SSMS 2012. It is 100% "hand-made" functionality - we needed to write own handler to implement it. You can define several guidelines (several column positions) and their color. Also we have added support to easily configure guidelines for SSMS 2008, without using the registry editor.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. It's hard to believe this type of functionality isn't there by default. I appreciate you adding it!

Comment: The plugin is great, but would be better if they didn't go through the text and it was only on where the tabbed sections are e.g. BEGIN / END.

Comment: Hi Andrei. Do you have any intention to make SSMSBoost available for the new 19 version of SSMS? We would be highly interested. Regards, Martin

Comment: Hello swissmawi, we just released new version version with SSMS 19.x support. I am very sorry for the interrupted release cycle. I am happy we are back online.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's do-able.  It all hinges on being able to install the Visual Studio 2010 Editor Guidelines extension into SSMS 2012.

I'd previously installed the Editor Guidelines extension to Visual Studio 2010.  [Here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0fbf2878-e678-4577-9fdb-9030389b338c) is the download page on the Visual Studio Gallery site (linked to in one of your Stackoverflow references).  Note that you need to install the Visual Studio 2010 extension, not the Visual Studio 2012 one (as SSMS 2012 is based on VS 2010, not VS 2012).

Now you need to find the extension folder for SSMS 2012. [This](http://blog.bagearon.com/2012/03/sql-server-management-studio-2012-color-themes-extension-support/) blog post from Brad Gearon pointed me in the right direction.  I found it at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\ .

Next you need to find the Editor Guidelines extension you previously installed into Visual Studio 2010.  [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/19/how-vsix-extensions-are-discovered-and-loaded-in-vs-2010.aspx) Visual Studio blog post pointed me to the master devenv.pkgdef file, which lists the various locations extensions can be saved to for Visual Studio 2010.  After trying various of the locations in the devenv.pkgdef file, I stumbled on the Editor Guidelines extension in C:\Users{your username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\ .  The extension is just a folder with a random seeming name, in my case zdtycyqi.0zr.  I had several extensions installed and, to find the right one, I went through each of the folders with the random names, opening the extension.vsixmanifest file in each.  Each extension.vsixmanifest file has a description element.  The one I selected had the description "Adds vertical column guides to the editor. Uses the same registry syntax as previous versions of Visual Studio.".

Now all you do is copy the whole folder containing the extension (in my case folder zdtycyqi.0zr ) from the Visual Studio extensions folder into the SSMS 2012 extensions folder.

To add guidelines I created a string value called Guides in registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Text Editor.  To set a guideline at column 100 I set the value of Guides to "RGB(196,0,0) 99".

Now when I open a query window in SSMS 2012 I see a dark red guideline at column 100.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't work for me. I tried to install the Editor Guidelines extension, but it wouldn't install because "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products." I tried just copying the contents of ColumnGuide.vsix (which is just a zip file) to a new folder named zdtycyqi.0zr at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions and added the Guides registry string, but no guideline. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I deleted folder zdtycyqi.0zr and confirmed that SSMS 2012 does not show any guidelines.  Then I downloaded the ColumnGuide.vsix extension file from the link I gave above.  I used 7 Zip to extract the contents of ColumnGuide.vsix to a folder called ColumnGuide, then copied that ColumnGuide folder to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\.  When I open SSMS then open a new query window the guideline appears.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that when creating the string value in the registry, don't put the double quotes around the RGB(196,0,0) 99 .  Sorry if that's a bit obvious but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I've got the quote-less registry entry and I double checked everything else, too, but it's still not working. Bummer. The only thing I can think of is that I'm not using the default editor color settings and that is interfering some how. I've got a dark background (the [VS-11 theme](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/vs-11-dark), specifically), but I've tried different line colors and nothing is showing.