# How to set print margin in Visual C# 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

Is there a setting in Visual C# 2008 to set a character width at which I'd like to see a margin line in the code editors? I do this in eclipse by: Window --> Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Text Editors --> Show Print Margin, Column = 80

But I couldn't find any print margin setting while searching online or poking around in the settings.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2010, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it's impossible from menu. But ome addins enables this feature, or you can edit the registry manually (not very good, but it works):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Text Editor]
"Guides"="RGB(212,212,212) 99, 109"
```

Here `RGB(212,212,212)` - margin color;  `99, 109` means that we want two margin guides: after 100-th and after 110-th character

Answer (score 2):

I poked around but couldn't find much.  For some languages, you can specify a length that tags will wrap at.  For example, HTML:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Format > Tag Wrapping
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your question more carefully, I did some more digging. Apparently [there's a registry hack](http://dream-runner.blogspot.com/2007/06/visual-studio-tips-80-character.html) you can do to make Visual Studio show a margin line at a certain number of characters (you can add up to 13 "guides"), but it sounds like it won't automatically wrap at that guide line when formatting like Eclipse does.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work for me. Perhaps it doesn't work for the Express edition. Thanks for the link!