# Override text rendering in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

I want to customize the way the text is *rendered* in Microsoft's Visual Studio text viewer. The goal is to implement my own complicated algorithm for whitespace handling.

Note: I've already written "add-ins" to automate some tasks (include guards, copyright insertion in the file's header etc...). However, as far as I understand, "add-ins" cannot be used to override the kind of functionality I need.

Is it possible to override the default text rendering? If yes, where do I start?

(Visual studio 2005 is preferred.)

Comment: Why tag C++ and C#? This isn't specific to either of them.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, you're right. Just wanted to specify that it doesn't matter what language to use...

Comment: @Voters as 'too localized': I find it more general than this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at Visual Studio language services. Try [Language Services on MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20130125013819/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165099(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: +1 Apparently this is the way to go. Unfortunately I can't find a customization point I need.

Comment: I'm afraid I've only dabbled in language services, so can't really give any further pointers.