# 100 characters line marker in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a guideline to the editor in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio)

Is there a way to display a vertical line at 80 or 100 characters in the editor of Visual Studio?

I know it is possible in Eclipse and coudn't find it in VS.

This vertical marker line help seeing when to break a line of code for people that do not go over 80 or 100 characters per line of code.

I am a Java developer that currently develop in C#, my habbit may not correspond to C# style guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need a line? I don't like big lines of codes and they clutter your code but in general the size of your monitor should be enough to see when your code is too big. I agree with the idea of a line to help if you work in a team that have different size of monitors.

Comment: The line help to always keep the same line size.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are using VS 2010, you can install [the Productivity Power Tools extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef), which provides this functionality.

The feature you're looking for is called "Column Guides". The PPT website states:

> Simply place the cursor at the appropriate column and select Add Guideline from the context menu

Comment: Thanks. That Was indeed what I was looking for. 
It is however surprising that this is not part of visual studio by default, especially since visual studio is soo big.

Comment: @user1162647 I just found that VS supports this without extensions, but it needs to be configured by hacking the Registry settings (I've no idea why). For details see http://stackoverflow.com/q/84209/390819

Comment: Are these guidelines permanent?

Comment: for `visual studio code` the setting i was looking for was `"editor.rulers"`