# How to set the guides (right-margin marks) in VS2012 text editors

Tags: text-editor, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to set the guides (right-margin marks) in the visual studio 2012 text editors without any extensions?

**Edit**: registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Text Editor doesn't work.
Any working solutions?

Comment: technically, yes: set the registry key by hand. Probably not what you wanted.

Comment: ok, can you please share the correct registry key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/84467/203458 For VS2012 you would use 11.0 rather than 10.0, 9.0 etc as you see in that answer

Comment: the registry key doesn't work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a guideline to the editor in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now is the [Paul Harrington's Editor Guidelines Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da227a0b-0e31-4a11-8f6b-3a149cf2e459) for the Visual Studio 2012 available. So you have an extended context menu, where you can Add, Remove or Change Color of the guidelines.

Comment: I love it! (But why isn't it built in, in Visual Studio? I started searching for this capability after seeing it in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and liking it.)