# Visual Studios 2012 Line Wrap?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, word-wrap

How would I go about setting up a line wrap line that runs up and down on Visual Studios 2012, just like what Netbeans has when you have too much on a single line?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the guides (right-margin marks) in VS2012 text editors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073277/how-to-set-the-guides-right-margin-marks-in-vs2012-text-editors)

Comment: Yup, but I didn't see it till you posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Advanced, Word Wrap.

Next time, try typing `wrap` in the Quick Launch box.

Comment: Not what I'm wanting, should have said I want a line that runs up and down telling me that if I pass this line, I might not see it on other screens.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da227a0b-0e31-4a11-8f6b-3a149cf2e459