# see line length in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I like to restrict to 80 characters in each line in my code for readability. I would like to know if there is any scale to show the line length in visual studio 2012 like how it shows the line number (I mean a horizontal scale?)

Comment: It does show Character Number & Column Number next to line number

Comment: VAssistX has what they call a *Column Indicator*: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/column.asp

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I can't see column number in mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Visual Studio Productivity Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) has a column guide setting which will draw a vertical column guide in the editor.

> **Column Guides**
>
> Draws a vertical line in the code editor to remind
>   developers that their full line of code or comments may not fit one a
>   single screen. Simply place the cursor at the appropriate column and
>   select Add Guideline from the context menu

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 9.0 used to have a way to do this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Text Editor]
"Guides"="RGB(200, 200, 200) 80"
```

Taken from: https://gist.github.com/rsneekes/843732

I seem to recall trying to get it to work when I upgraded to VS 2010, but it got to be more trouble than it was worth.  I wonder why (or if) they removed it.

Also: Possible duplicate of:
[Adding a guideline to the editor in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio)

Of course, I find nothing working without some extension past 2008 for myself.