# Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

#### Rendering More than One Ruler in VS Code

---

VS Code's default configuration for a ruler is demonstrated below.

```json
"editor.ruler": 80
```

The issue I am having with the default VS Code configuration *(as shown above)* is that it only renders a single ruler. In the **Sublime Text Editor** I can render as many rulers as I like using the following Sublime configuration.

```json
"rulers": [72, 80, 100, 120]
```

Is it possible to render multiple rulers in V.S. Code. If it is possible, What does a multi-ruler configuration look like in **VS Code**?

Comment: Is there a way to use a dashed line instead of a solid line? Or any other style line for that matter.

Comment: There is no current method for implementing any sort of line, other than a solid line, however, if you see the answer I posted below, the solid line is actually quite customizable.

Answer (score 2549, accepted):

Visual Studio Code 0.10.10 introduced this feature. To configure it, go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* and add this to to your user or workspace settings:

```json
"editor.rulers": [80,120]
```

The color of the rulers can be customized like this:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#ff4081"
}
```

Comment: Also, you could try this extention https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SirTori.indenticator

Comment: If a PyLint [complaint brought you here (message C0301 , enforcing PEP 8)](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0301) -- notice they mention the ideal length for Python , which [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) says is **79**

Comment: I needed to re-start VS Code for this to take effect. Version 1.13.0

Comment: VS Code no longer requires a restart in order to apply this setting as of 1.31.1, probably sooner.

Comment: What does the second number stand for?

Comment: @nocibambi Multiple rulers are supported. The second number will display a second ruler at column 120

Comment: how to make "editor.rulers": [${ColumnLimit}] which ColumnLimit is specified in .clang-format

Comment: When will the second number will be used? When there is word-splitting not possible?

Comment: Seems to only work in global settings, doesn't work in workspace settings

Comment: On a Mac, it's in Code -> Preferences -> Settings.

Comment: Excellent with the color example! That was going to be my next question (:

Answer (score 440):

In addition to global `"editor.rulers"` setting, it's also possible to set this on a per-language level.

For example, style guides for Python projects often specify either 79 or 120 characters vs. Git commit messages should be no longer than 50 characters.

So in your `settings.json`, you'd put:

```json
"[git-commit]": {"editor.rulers": [50]},
"[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [
        79,
        120
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I use this option for manually editing Git commit messages in the editor (rather than in command line). If you already have a default value for all other languages' file formats (for example `"editor.rulers": [ 80 ]` per Drupal coding standards) in general scope, then it's possible to overwrite only for the Git commit messages file format by adding this to the end of your `settings.json` file:
```
    "[git-commit]": {
        "editor.rulers": [ 50 ],
    }
```
This way it's totally separated, does not affect other language files.

Comment: You can now also specify individual colours on the rulers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031111/23118) for details.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it definitively makes sense to do that language specific.

Answer (score 199):

With Visual Studio Code 1.27.2:

1. When I go to *File > Preference > Settings*, I get the following tab

   > [image: Screenshot]
2. I type *rulers* in *Search settings* and I get the following list of settings

   > [image: screenshot]
3. Clicking on the first *Edit in settings.json*, I can edit the user settings

   > [image: screenshot]
4. Clicking on the pen icon that appears to the left of the setting in *Default user settings* I can copy it on the user settings and edit it

With Visual Studio Code 1.38.1, the screenshot shown on the third point changes to the following one.

[image]

The panel for selecting the default user setting values isn't shown anymore.

Comment: Strange, clicking on "Edit in settings.json" just opens the json and doesn't add a default entry either. I need to click on the gear icon (it only appears when hovering the setting) -> Copy Setting ID / as JSON, then paste it in the User Settings. How did you get the dual pane Default/User settings? I use VS code v1.38.1.

Comment: I was using VSC 1.27.2. Version 1.38.1 doesn't show the dual panel anymore. It's similar to the settings window used from Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Too bad. If the default isn't shown in dual pane, they could as least insert a stub `"editor.rulers": [80]` so the user doesn't have to copy the JSON manually. The GUI settings window doesn't even show the current value for `editor.rulers`, like a few others...

Answer (score 171):

In v1.43 is the ability to separately color the vertical rulers.

See issue *[Support multiple rulers with different colors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54312)*  - (in settings.json):

```json
"editor.rulers": [
  {
    "column": 80,
    "color": "#ff00FF"
  },
  100,  // <- a ruler in the default color or as customized (with "editorRuler.foreground") at column 100
  {
    "column": 120,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  },
]
```

To change the default color for a ruler:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorRuler.foreground": "#fffa"   
            // or "#ffffffaa" - the a's are alpha transparency values
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can also add transparency to the colors. For example: `"color": "#9688b7a1"`

Answer (score 76):

Visual Studio Code: Version 1.14.2 (1.14.2)

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open palette

   - For non-macOS users, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Enter "settings.json" to open setting files.
3. At default setting, you can see this:

   ```json
   // Columns at which to show vertical rulers
   "editor.rulers": [],
   ```

   This means the empty array won't show the vertical rulers.
4. At right window "user setting", add the following:

```json
"editor.rulers": [140]
```

Save the file, and you will see the rulers.

Comment: Re `Ctrl` + `P` for non-macOS users: Are you sure it is not `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `P`?

Comment: I did not find `At right window "user setting", add the following`. Instead, I opened the "settings.json" that was not default (the shortest length of "settings.json" that can be found and it was empty. Fill it for example with `{"editor.rulers": [50,79,120], }` or use a language-wise setting.

Answer (score 44):

## Customizing VS Code's Char-len Ruler:

---

The following answer is far more recent than the other answers provided for this question, therefore; it is important to note that this answer contains information & content not provided by any of the other answers. I have formatted the question below into 4 configurations. Each configuration builds on top of the last configuration, consequently; The first configuration is simple, and offers a simple result, whereas the last  configuration is more complex and offers much more.

For your convenience, I have included images at the bottom of each configuration's example. The images allow you to view a configuration, then see the result that the configuration has. This is important, because without the images you would have to bounce back and forth between here & your editor to see what each configuration looks like.

---

### Config #1 | The Obvious Single Ruler Config

---

The obvious setting is the setting that has been suggested many times over. I will mention it here, just because it is the correct place to start.

- Add the following **JSON Property** to your `settings.json` file.

```json
{
    "editor.rulers": [80]
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE!** It may be required that you reload the instance of **VS Code** (semantically speaking: *some refer to this as reloading the window*) being configured to get the newly added configuration to render as expected. (*to see how to reload your window quickly, scroll to the end of this answer*).

###### *Once the configuration takes, your editor should look like this:*

[image: Image demonstrates the result when the editor.ruler setting in VS Code is configured with a single value]

---

### Config #2 | Multiple Rulers

---

Obviously the ruler takes an array as its assigned value. The array allows VSC users to add multiple rulers.

- Be simply adding one value to the configuration in the last example (*as shown in the snippet below*) we can add another ruler.

```json
{
    "editor.rulers": [80, 125]
}
```

The screen shot I took is a bit short, but it communicates the point well enough. You can see that there are now two vertical lines, rather than a single line. Many front-end developers opt for this configuration because 125 is often used as the preferred line-length for HTML, and 80 is the preferred line-length for JavaScript embedded in HTML documents.

[image: Image demonstrates the result when the editor.ruler setting in VS Code is configured with more than one value]

---

### Config #3 | Coloring the Ruler

---

This configuration demonstrates the whimsy side of playing with VS Code's configuration; and the ruler is certainly one of the more whimsical editor-features that VS Code ships with. This configuration shows you how to color the configuration we used above. To be able to custom color the rulers, it is required that an additional setting be added to the configuration, take a look below:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor-ruler.foreground": "#0099AA"
    },

    "editor.rulers": [80, 125]
}
```

###### *Below you can see the awesomeness of the pacific blue color!*

[image]

---

### Config #4 | Coloring the Ruler so it works w/ Code

---

So, as awesome as beautiful pacific-blue rulers are, they are not always practical. The opaque — *and in this case highly contrasted* — rulers streak right behind are code which can greatly decrease the readability of your code. For this very reason, developers generally opt for a configuration that places a single ruler at the desired line length, however, there is another way. By adjusting the previous configuration ever so slightly, we can render the rulers in a way that is much less intrusive. Take a look at the configuration below.

###### *Do you see the subtle change?*

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor-ruler.foreground": "#0099AA33"
    },

    "editor.rulers": [80, 125]
}
```

Below demonstrates where the change was made:

- **Color used in the 3rd configuration:**

  - ```json
    "editor-ruler.foreground": "#0099AA"
    ```
- **Color used in the 4th configuration:**

  - ```json
    "editor-ruler.foreground": "#0099AA33"
    ```

The new configuration's adjusted chromatic value (the color/hue) renders transparently (or not at 100% opacity), *in-other-words*; the rulers are rendered to be partially transparent (approximately 25% transparency).

The change has a rather significant effect because opaque rulers hinder readability, and can distract the programmer from her code. A programmer may opt for transparent rulers because transparent rulers will allow her to measure the length of her code at any length intervals she chooses, without hindering the readability of the code.

##### See the transparent rulers below? *You might want to click on the image to see the larger view.*

[image: Example shows a colored ruler in VS Code]

---

### Config #5 | The Ultimate Customized Ruler

---

The problem with transparent rulers is that they are not quite as fancy as the other rulers, fortunately, there's a way to get the best of both worlds. This example uses two images (*or screen-shots*): One image that shows the configuration, just like the other images you have been viewing above, and the other is a final image showing the configuration I use. The configuration I use is shown as a way to help put into perspective what you're able to accomplish with a good ruler configuration.

###### Below is a crazy sort of configuration...

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorRuler.foreground": "#00999922"
    },

    "editor.rulers": [
        20, 40, 40, 60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80
    ]
}
```

**I KNOW CRAZY RIGHT?!**

This configuration, looks nutter-butter, but it actually produces a very interesting, and highly customized sort of result. I really like this example because it offers a great demonstration of how the ruler array-property configuration works, and what can be accomplished with it.

###### *Here is the result*:

[image: Multiple Transparent Rulers]

**Notice what is happening?**

Each ruler is brighter than the last. The rulers are doing this because we are laying several transparent rulers over each other. With ever layer the rulers color becomes more saturated. This is an extremely fun effect to play with.

---

###### Like I said above, I will show you I use this effect to configure my environment:

[image: Customized rulers in a customized environment]

Note that I make all of the rulers very transparent except for the last two. This offers a snazy environment, while still keeping things practical. Having several rulers also helps me to format and organize my code. I am so use to having them now that I can hardly stand to work in an environment without them.

If I work on a project with a style-guide that enforces an 80 character limit, I often will place one line at 80, and another at 90. I write my code such that it breaks before, or at, 80 chars, however I don't like the 80 char limit personally, I feel that the standard should be 85 - 90 chars. 80 really makes developers feel like there pushed into a box. So if I don't like the way a line looks at 80, I will extend it to 90. Before I commit, I look at the file and I can quickly see everywhere I went over 80, I add line-breaks, the commit. then I use ctrl+z to reset the line breaks so the extend past 80.

Another purpose, Is when I comment, I prefer to end my comments at 70, it helps me visually distinguish between comments and code. When you have the extra lines, there is a good chance you'll start using them to do all sorts of your own little formatting customs.

---

---

###### *The resource below only pertains to those who are in need of instruction on reloading there instance of VS Code.*

#### RELOADING YOUR WINDOW IN VS CODE

To reload your window, press **<kbd>F1</kbd>** to open the **Quick-input Menu**. You should see the menu drop open, type `Developer: Reload Window`, then select the `Developer: Reload Window` option from the drop-down menu.

Comment: you're a genius... love it

Answer (score 41):

To expand on the above, you can set multiple rulers and colors for each ruler.  The default color *appears* to be "#5a5a5a", and if you tack on two additional digits to the end you can adjust its transparency to make some rulers more faint than others.

Here are my rulers, defined in a concise manner that's easier to edit.

```json
"editor.rulers": [
    {"column":   0, "color": "#5a5a5a80"}, // left boundary is 50% opaque
    {"column":   2, "color": "#5a5a5a20"}, // tab stops are 12.5% opaque
    {"column":   4, "color": "#5a5a5a20"},
    {"column":   6, "color": "#5a5a5a20"},
    {"column":   8, "color": "#5a5a5a20"},
    {"column":  10, "color": "#5a5a5a20"},
    {"column":  40, "color": "#5a5a5a20"}, // center line
    {"column":  79, "color": "#5a5a5a20"}, // right rule minus one
    {"column":  80, "color": "#5a5a5a80"}, // right rule
    {"column": 120, "color": "#5a5a5a40"}  // extra right rule
],
```

Comment: I like this. I changed slightly, replaced`#5a5a5a` with `#0099AA`. But thank you.

Answer (score 16):

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings Or <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. type "rulers" and click **Edit Setings.json**

[image]
3. Add the size value by ',' As you wish

[image]
**Like this(Gif)**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Combining [the answers of kiamlaluno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code/52455857#52455857) [and Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code/60292520#60292520), along with `formatOnSave` to auto-indent code for Python:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.autoIndent": "advanced",
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.rulers": [
        {
            "column": 79,
            "color": "#424142"
        },
        100, // <- a ruler in the default color or as customized at column 0
        {
            "column": 120,
            "color": "#ff0000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to Menu *File -> Preferences -> Settings* and add:

```json
"editor.rulers": [preferred-value, preferred-value]
```

[The color can be customized](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) in:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#00AA00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like [this explanation](https://dev.to/brad_beggs/vs-code-vertical-rulers-for-prettier-code-3gp3). It also tells how to set different colors for more than one ruler.

> Color and multiple vertical rulers are available in VS Code as of the [February 2020 edition](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54312).

For example:

```json
"editor.rulers": [
  {
    "column": 80,
    "color": "#ff9900"
  },
    100,
  {
   "column": 120,
   "color": "#9f0af5"
  },
],
```

To target a specific language:

```json
"[ruby]": {
  "editor.rulers": [
    {
      "column": 100,
      "color": "#00ff22"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Flutter then you need to edit the ruler for dart, you'll navigate to the file from RUN command:
%APPDATA%\code\User\settings.json

and set the ruler to 0

like in the picture.[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMzGJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got a last version for today of VS code **"1.83"**

This is what is works for me [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.io/editor/vscode-word-wrap/).

or you can do this like this :
[image]