# Disable (or toggle) the wavy underline/squigglies (problems) in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code (v1.11.2).
Is there any way to disable wavy underline at all?
[image]

Comment: I understand you. Wavy underlines can impede reading. However disabling them is not a good idea because they often give you important information. My suggestion is to change the color such that they blend somewhat with the background, for example by setting opacity, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610661/220060

Comment: As there is no Q/A for the same thing in VS2019 (visual studio express), and as this comes to the top of that google query as well, goto to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts-And-Colors, find "Warnings" and make them white. Ditto with "Syntax Error" (or make it pale red).

Comment: The wavy underling thing should have a visibility toggle since that color thing likely fails when the scheme is changed from day time to night time. Considering all the other notifications the wavy underline is perhaps now overrated, especially when it is obscuring an entire section of code to inform you of an incorrect result type...redundantly to other notifications.

Comment: Related (if you want to debounce/delay instead of disable/toggle): [In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to delay displaying inline errors when editing C# code, perhaps until I save the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64719791).

Comment: **I've written an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74934214/11107541)** and am waiting for that Q&A to get merged into this one. It has important information about the VS Code 1.85+ update(s).

Answer (score 141, accepted):

To **disable** wavy/squiggly underline in vscode, [go to settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) (Ctrl + Shift + P to access the Command Palette and type “settings.json”) and set underline color to fully transparent:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground":   "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00000000"
    }
}
```

Though it may be better to make underline color just **less vibrant**:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground":   "#ff000088",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#ffe60033",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00ff0088"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In VSCode, those green squiggly lines mean a warning in your code.
VSCode performs background code analysis([Linting](http://csslint.net/)) in order to provide you feedback about syntax and compilation errors.

In your particular case it is caused because of an **empty CSS ruleset** (declaring a selector but no properties).
You can see the warning message by hovering mouse pointer over code with the green squiggly line underneath.

[image: warning message VScode]

You can disable the wavyline by disabling linting for CSS.

Go to **File --> Preferences --> Settings** and then place following line in **Settings.json**

```
"css.validate": false
```

Alternatively you can also change default behavior of empty ruleset which is ***"css.lint.emptyRules": "warning"*** to ***ignore***
[image: VSCode settings.json]
There are also options to disable validating HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: Is it possible to let VS-code disable to wavy-lines when the line is 140 chars or more?

This is not a coding error. So I see no reason to not to disable it.

Comment: @AverageJoe check these answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447642/disable-white-vertical-line

Comment: and this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: To disable some linters to hide the wavy-lines is not a good option IMO. They could simply show an icon near the line numbers column, warnings are helpful - another way could be to allow to change the color of that lines perhaps

Answer (score 4):

When using Python, the common advice is to use shift-ctrl/cmd-P, then set `Python: Enable/Disable Linting` > `Disable` and `Python: Select Linter` > `Disable Linting`. Neither of those was enough for me. Nor was I able to disable these by turning off the dozen or so linters listed under `Settings` > search > `linting`.

However, I was finally able to disable the wavy red underlines via `Settings` > `Python: Language Server` > `None`.

By the way, you can see where these underlines are coming from via `View` > `Problems`. In my case, they were coming from PyLance, and after I removed that extension, they came from Jedi instead. Even though I don't have the Jedi installed. It seems like Microsoft's own Python extension has Jedi somewhere inside and uses that unless you turn off the Language Server entirely.

Comment: I'm trying to get ride of the wavy yellow ones. The breezy advice to disable linting is happily ignored by vscode. Setting the language server to None helped me.

Answer (score 3):

VSC Version: 1.45.1

Solution: Disable "JavaScript ESLint Enable" for JavaScript files.

1. Open Command Palette by 'Ctrl+Shift+P'.
2. From Command Palette find and click: 'Preferences: Open Workspace Settings'.
3. From 'Workspace Settings' into search field type 'javascript'. From left sidebar look for Extensions -> ESLint.
4. Click 'ESLint' and from right look for 'ESLint: Enable'.
5. Uncheck 'ESLint Enable'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario:** **VScode 1.35.1** with installed extension "**StandardJS - JavaScript Standard Style**".

1. The extension in javascript files: underlines some code, checks for indent spaces, etc.
2. How to stop javascript code style validation ?

**Solution:** **Disable** "**JavaScript Standard Style**" for JavaScript files.

1. Open Command Palette by 'Ctrl+Shift+P'.
2. From Command Palette find and click: 'Preferences: Open Workspace Settings'.
3. From '**Workspace Settings**' into **search field** type '**javascript**'. From **left sidebar** look for **Extensions** -> **JavaScript Standard Style**.
4. Click 'JavaScript Standard Style' and from right look for '**Standard: Enable**'.
5. **Uncheck** 'Standard Enable'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Ruby` and those are the files that you want to disable the warnings for, open the preferences file `settings.json` and modify the ruby linting rules as follows:

```
    "ruby.lint":
    {
        "rubocop": false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If in dart in the flutter project, blue wavy lines are coming all over the code in the dart file, then make sure that you have saved the file with a name that contains lowercase and underscore characters only.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, using VS Code circa v1.78.2, this worked:

- Navigate to Extensions
- Find Pylint, click the gear icon and select Disable
- Find Pylance, click the gear icon and select Disable
- Restart of VS Code was required and disabling both Pylint and Pylance was required

Answer (score 0):

There is a new setting in Insiders v1.85 to hide the Problems squigglies in the editors and the editor tabs and the Explorer (see demo below).

The setting is:

```
Problems: Visibility
Controls whether the problems are visible throughout the editor and workbench.
```

Unfortunately, it is a setting only and not a command that can **TOGGLE** the problems visibility on and off quickly.

If you want to be able to quickly toggle it on and off by a keybinding, you will need an extension such as [Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle), written by a then-vscode team member - there may be other toggle settings extensions.

Here is a keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) that will toggle the `Problems: Visibility` setting on and off:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",           // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "toggle",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
      "id": "problems",
      "value": [
          {
            "problems.visibility": false
          },
          {
            "problems.visibility": true
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

Demo showing the setting working:

[image: problems visibility setting]

Demo of the Toggle keybinding:

[image: Problems visibility toggle]

When the `Problems: Visibility` setting is off, there will be a small notification in the Taskbar which when clicked will take you to the Setting UI with that setting:

[image: Problems visibility disabled taskbar notification]

The `Toggle` extension keybinding will also cause this taskBar notification to appear.

---

---

Previous answer:

A suggestion to upvote this more recent GH Issue: [Provide the ability to disable warning/error squiggles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194392).  It is a backlog candidate but needs votes so that disabling the squigglies can be done across languages without resorting to the transparent trick.

Also definitely upvote [Toggle problem visibility in Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166797): same issue, already on the Backlog.

Comment: pretty sure that issue ticket is a dup of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166797, which I mention in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/74753185/11107541, which I'd like now to close as a dup of this question (if you'd be willing to help with that).

Comment: @starball Yes, lots of GH issues on this.  But the issue I mentioned was marked as a `Backlog Candidate` so it doesn't seem like it will be closed as a dup. (especially if it gets upvoted quickly).  It also has very good comments.

Comment: I don't see what is especially great about the comments there and the dup-target I proposed is already on the backlog, which if I understand correctly, is better than just being a candidate for the backlog.

Comment: @starball You are right, the latest GH issue should be closed in favor of the one you mentioned.  But the comments on the latest are good, especially as to why the workarounds are not useful.  I updated the answer with the older issue.

Answer (score -2):

Right Click in your editor window and select for 'Command Pallet' option

OR press CTRL+SHIFT+P and search for the option 'Enable Error Squiggle' and just click on it. That's it! If you want to Disable Red Wavy underlines showed after syntax error, just Follow the above procedure and search for 'Disable Error Squiggle' and click on it.

Comment: squiggle is not found when i type ctrl shift p

Answer (score -6):

Disable wavy underline in VS Code in C on mac

1. Press command+shift+p (open command pallete)
2. Then type Disable Error Squiggles
3. And click on that Disable Error Squiggles

Your squiggles are no more

If you want to restart squiggles for some reason
then in command pallete type Enable Error Squiggles

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There's not a single command with `Squiggle` in the name. Di I need an extension for your suggestion? Because it sounds awesome