# Disable White Vertical Line

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I've installed VS Code on my Mac and it works perfectly fine. There's just this white vertical line going down the screen which is kinda annoying.

I'm not sure if it's supposed to be some sort of guide, ruler or something. It just appeared from the start. Is there a way to disable it?

It looks like this :

[image]

Comment: indeed, that's so annoying. I hope the guy who had the idea to put this on by default from a sudden will realize most of us hate it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was bugging me a lot as well... so I finally tracked down the setting which turned it off.

[image]

Answer (score 117):

In the ***settings.json*** there can be **2 places**, where it has ****"editor.rulers"**** .
****Make both empty****.
To find the settings json refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file).

[image]

Comment: this issue always come with dart

Comment: Let's be honest, who actually wants this "feature"?

Comment: FYI in Ubuntu, find these settings in `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: Windows: %appdata%\code\user\settings.json

Comment: not working anymore

Answer (score 30):

By default the ruler shouldn't be visible, but you can check for the following setting:

`editor.rulers`.

If set, it's an array with column numbers. If you want to turn it off, you can simply set an empty array like this:

`"editor.rulers": []`

Comment: So I checked my settings and "editor.rulers": [] is set exactly as you have it already. It must be something else.

Comment: Workspace settings would be the next place to look.

Comment: Another idea: It was enabled by an extension, does it go away if you start the editor from the command line with `code --disable-extensions`?

Comment: @StormKrow This should be marked the correct answer. e.g:
`"editor.rulers": [80, 100, 120]` if you remove those values i.e `80, 100 and 120` you won't see the lines anymore.

Answer (score 24):

In the latest version of vscode you can follow this process to get rid of that white line

Step 1: Go to Preferences -> Settings
[image: Screenshot of the preferences panel]

Step 2: Search for editor rulers and click on edit in settings.json
[image: Screenshot of the search result]

Step 3: In many cases, it would be like this:

```
"editor.rulers": [
  80
]
```

Remove 80 and make it an empty array and save it.

```
"editor.rulers": []
```

By following these steps the vertical line should be removed.

Answer (score 12):

As my dart file was having that issue. So I have added in setting.json:

```
"[dart]" : {

"editor.rulers": []
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you search in your settings file - the default settings that is - you will find

> // Controls whether the editor should render indent guides
>
> "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,

Set that to false in your user settings - typically the right panel if you open "Settings' from the lower left gear icon.

You can also change the indent guides color if you wish.  See [Change indent color in theme for VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447928/change-indent-color-in-theme-for-vscode/45448724#45448724) to learn how to do so.  Generally you can find a lot by opening up your Settings and then searching through the default settings.

Comment: I just tried that and it still doesn't get rid of the white line on the far right. It only removed the indentations lines. I'm not sure if the white line on the right side is some kind of ruler or column guide or something.

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned guide or ruler so I thought you were referring to the lines on the left.  Is your screen split by any chance?  Just on a lark does "scrollbar.shadow": "#f00", in the "workbench.colorCustomizations" make it change color?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't get ride of the white line.

Answer (score 5):

`settings.json`

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#00000000"//transparent
  }
}
```

[Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code/29972073#29972073)

Answer (score 4):

If u just want to get rid of the rightmost line, edit your settings.json file

```
"editor.rulers": [],
```

And if you want to get rid of the left sidelines, just make sure

[image: render indent guides]

Comment: _Indent Guides_ is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: hit Ctrl + P and search for settings.json

Answer (score 1):

steps for solution:

1. click ctrl+, in vs code editor, or manually open the setting in vscode editor.
2. search for editor rulers and after a search click on Edit in settings.json
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkgoe.png)
3. make editor rulers empty.
4. close the tap
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNnRx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps:

- Open vs code `settings.json` file
- then under json file search for this line of code `"editor.rulers":`
  [image]
- then remove the or blank the array like this`"editor.rulers": [],` and save the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + Shift + P => Type: setting.json and then click "Open Settings (JSON)

[image]

Then change to this: "editor.rulers": [],

Answer (score 0):

It is better to move the line.
Add in settings.json this code:

`"editor.rulers": [120], "editor.wordWrapColumn": 120, "editor.wordWrap": "off", "dart.lineLength": 120,`

Hope this can work for you

PD: 120 is an example put the number that you want

Answer (score -1):

in dart language, set this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6C1p.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541 https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the Run command by pressing `Windows+R`
2. In the Run command window, type `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` and press `Enter`
3. This will open the `settings.json` file in Visual Studio Code.
4. In the settings.json file, find the following line `editor.rulers = []`
5. Remove the 80 in `editor.rulers[]`
6. Save the `settings.json` file. [Image of VSCode settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoSP6.png)

Comment: This is already well covered in the existing answers. Please don't repeat answers.