# How to remove error/warning underline from a line in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I develop LKM and vscode does not recognize `linux/init.h>` (it shouldn't), but it is required for developing LKM's, I want to remove this red underline because it annoying. Is there way I can remove this highlighting?

[An example of what I remove to remove (red underline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dms9.png)

Comment: Unfortunatly I think you need to disable all code parsing or create a "fake" init.h along with the other headers.

Comment: check this out [Disable wavy underline in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454967/disable-wavy-underline-in-vs-code)