# How do I disable the underlining of Rust variables and their methods in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

[image]

How do I disable the underlining of variables and their methods,  like shown above? I find it quite distracting.

I don't think this is a duplicate of [Disable wavy underline in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43454967/155423) because it's not a wavy underline.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The underline is intended to draw attention to mutable variables and methods. It can be disabled by adding the following to your `settings.json`:

```
{
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "*.mutable": {
                "underline": false,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As someone who is legally, but not completely, blind this has always been a hindrance. I had no idea this could be turned off. Thank you for the question, and for posting the solution.

Comment: Command palette > open user settings | add it to the json file it opens.

Comment: Prima! Danke schön.
Personally, I rather like the visual hinting that something is either mutable or a mutator (it takes `self` mutably) but the weight of the underline is just too much – it is far more striking than the characters of the font, itself, and thus it detracts from legibility. I don't have the time or the will to work out how to style that – at least, not now – so turning it off is what I will do.

Comment: It is also possible to specify that this should be only for Rust by using `"*.mutable:rust"`.

Comment: Do note that there's a trailing comma on one of the lines which isn't technically valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to `settings.json`

```
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
```

Comment: This does do the trick, though it also changes the colors of other things like macros, member-accesses, consts, and types (depending where its at) since they are no longer indicated as-to their semantic meaning. But of course people can decide for themselves if that's what they want.