# VSCode underline hides wavy line

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-language-server

Underlines which signify Types and Namespaces obscure wavy underlines which signify errors and warnings. This makes it difficult for me to find the location of errors and warnings visually.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any solutions?

This particular example is with the Rust language, but I imagine the problem might show up in other languages.

[image: WavyLineHiddenByUnderline]

[image: WavyLineNotHidden]

Comment: Can you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014469/729541) please?

Comment: You TextMate tokens need adjusting. You can do this in your settings, or in your theme. You do want to make-sure an extension isn't overriding both your theme JSON file, and your settings.json file though.

Comment: Ah, it was the theme. I solved the issue by switching to a better theme. Thank you!