# In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to delay displaying inline errors when editing C# code, perhaps until I save the file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code primarily to edit C# code, and it automatically detects errors in the code as I type. However because it updates this every second or so, that means that the moment I start typing something on a line and pause even for a brief moment, I've technically introduced a syntax error and it highlights it with a red underline, until finally the whole line is typed.

This is very distracting! I like having it tell me where errors are, but I'd much rather have it wait until I've finished what I'm typing, or even better when I've saved the file, since at that point I expect the code to be correct.

Is there any way to configure VS Code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) v0.4.0.

Now you can change workbench colors when the file is dirty (not saved) (experimental)

This only works for files in a Workspace. The extension needs a workspace because it will not change the global workbench color customization.

Add the following to your settings (Global or Workspace)

```json
  "whenFile.change": {
    "byLanguageId": {
      "csharp": {
        "whenDirty": {
          "editorError.foreground": "#ff000020",
          "editorWarning.foreground": "#ff000020",
          "editorInfo.foreground": "#ff000020"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When you start typing the squiggles will be very faint red. If you save the file they will get the theme colors back. Every theme uses different squiggles colors but faint red is not a problem. Also the icons in the PROBLEMS panel become transparent.

If you have customized these colors you have to put these in a theme group of `workbench.colorCustomizations`. But it can be that theme groups override the colors.

I will add a timer to reset this state when you haven't typed for x seconds.

If your theme uses the other colors in the groups `editorError`, `editorWarning`, `editorInfo` you can add these too.

Comment: This might be the best solution I've encountered so far. It's not truly what I want, since it only hides the squiggles and doesn't prevent the 'Problems' pane from updating, and ideally the errors and warnings would persist after I've saved but have started typing again. (Preferably the error would disappear if I start editing the line it applies to.) Obviously that's outside the purview of When File, though, and I think it might be good enough. It does certainly solve the problem of the distracting squiggles!

Comment: @BriBri Instead of using `#ff000020` you can use `#ff000000` to make them transparent

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: @BriBri you can hide the PROBLEMS panel so you don't see the changes, you can get the same info from the tooltips

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this is that there is still no way to add a **delay** to the code validation.  See [Intellisense, Add an option to delay validation (and thus wavy lines in code).](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74798)

The unsatisfactory solution provided there is to disable validation altogether until a save operation:

> On second thought , this is exactly what tasks already do. Just
> disable the built-in js/ts validator using javascript.validate.enable:
> false + typescript.validate.enable: false and setup a task to build
> your project instead. It should only update errors when the file on
> disk changes (i.e. you save it). You can also configure autosave if
> wish to have this happen after a delay

You would have to see if your cSharp language server provides an option to run validation `onSave` or `onType`.

- I just looked through all the settings for csharp and omnisharp in vscode and found nothing similar to the validate only on save option or to disable validation altogether.

For php there is such an option built-in: `PHP > Validate: Run`.  `onSave` or `onType`.

Comment: After quite a lot of digging, what I've found is that Microsoft's C# extension simply has no options to change its validation behavior. It can't be disabled, it can't be delayed, and it can't be postponed until the file is saved. If I'm wrong then please do correct me.

Comment: @BriBri I agree, I just looked through all the settings for `csharp` and `omnisharp` in vscode and found nothing simila to the validate only on save option or disable altogether.

Answer (score 1):

---

Open up the command palette (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) - > c/c++: Disable Error Squiggles. This will disable all error warnings and highlighting.

---

Comment: This works for C/C++, but unfortunately not for C#.