VSCode underlines entire Typescript function on error
In certain cases, when the function returns an incorrect type, VSCode underlines the entire function.
What usually happens is I'm in the process of typing the function code, so obviously it's not completed yet, and the red underline makes it very annoying to look at the code.
Is there any setting to change this (I don't want to disable error underlines as a whole)?


what should it underline instead? What it underlines is what is producing the (2|0|1|undefined)[] value. Maybe try baz.map<number>(...) to tell TypeScript that the result is number[] and so you'd get something like "not all paths return a value" (which would probably still underline the whole function).

Also don't post images of your code. The TS playground also shows your issue (so it's not a vscode one) and it's much easier to work with texts and sandboxes rather than with images

Ah, didn't know TS playground has the same highlighting, I would've done that then. It should probably highlight the number[] on parent function, just like it would do if I add explicit return type to the inner function (in that case the return type would be highlighted).

If you do bar.map<number[]>(baz => baz.map<number>(id => { ... })) it's equivalent to specifying a return type to the inner functions. You will still get an error in the inner one saying "not all paths return a value" but I guess that's more helpful (sandbox)

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64719791/11107541 (?)
