# How to hide ESlint/webpack's HMR error overlay

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint

After I run `npm run dev` `nuxt` builds the app and displays it and a second later a partly transparent full-viewport modal gets displayed on top of the app (in the browser) listing very 'helpfully' a bunch of eslint errors.

I would like to keep the errors being printed in terminal, but not displayed on top of the page I'm working on.

Can this be achieved? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about the same thing (image below), this should be done thanks to this globally applied CSS

```css
#webpack-hot-middleware-clientOverlay {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

---

You are talking about the squiggles under your code? This can be solved with this IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610661/8816585

`settings.json` (VScode's palette + `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`)

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
    "editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, no, I mean the modal that gets displayed over the rendered page in the browser

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot! I didn't expect this kind of solution, but it works, so good enough for me. :D

Comment: @Eggon there is probably nothing baked into the framework, but this is good enough yeah!