# How do I hide linter problems in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I've opened some random Python file in Code, and it is filled with linter issues producing many squiggly colored underlines all over.

Is there a way to hide those squiggly lines without disabling linters? I'm just looking for a way to quickly toggle them off and on. Thanks.

I searched settings and commands and online but didn't find an answer yet. Zen mode wasn't even zen enough in this case. Putting the file in Plain Text mode removes them, but also eliminates colorizing the code, which I wish to retain.

addendum: I opened a feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166797

Comment: with the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) you can make them transparent while the file is dirty

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77239436/836330 for how to TOGGLE those problem squigglies on and off.