# How to disable or make less visible the wavy underlines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Strong underscores make it hard for me to focus. A number of solutions are described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454967/disable-wavy-underline-in-vs-code), but it is outdated. I wanted to try the solution in the link, however, the options described do not appear in VS Code.

Is there an up to date solution?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked post works for me still, so what about it isn't working for you?

Comment: Things specified in the command palette do not appear for me?

Comment: You shouldn't need to be using the command palette to modify your settings.json according to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610661/6530134). Just add that json to your settings file (assuming you are using dark mode theme)

Comment: Oh!! I noticed it with what you said. Yeah. It turned out very well when I added the relevant code to the setting.json. Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of [Disable wavy underline in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454967/disable-wavy-underline-in-vs-code)